# is there a way to click on one link that trigger inline editing of another area (not where you clicked)

Tags: jquery, jeditable

i want to click on a link that will cause another area to become editable (not the link that i click).  is this possible with jeditable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plugin you are using `JEditable` monitors the elements you've tagged with a specific class for the 'click` event and then enabled the editing of the element once you've clicked it.

You can easily fire the `click` event from another element like this:

```
$("a#click_to_edit").click(function(){
  $("#editme").triggerHandler("click");
  return false;
})
```

.

```
<p id="editme" class="editable_textarea">Some Text to Edit</p>
<a id="click_to_edit" href="#">click me to edit the paragraph above</a>
```

Comment: thanks. one issue i have is that my clicks are based off of class selectors (not ids).  is there anyway to get the div in the current row of a html table ?

Comment: oo, update your question with the exact HTML structure that you are working with, and I'll modify my answer to match it.